# Run Existing Web Start App Through IDE Using Existing JNLP(s)

Tags: jnlp

I have an existing application that I need to debug. On the web server it uses 2 JNLP files, one containing many parameter settings needed by the application. I am trying to get this to run through my IDE (netbeans) with no success. Netbeans allows me to set up the application as a web start app but creates the JNLP files itself (no good because I need the parameters). I am left with placing all of the parameters in an HTML  file and running the app through sun.applet.AppletViewer. I've scoured Google and the forums looking for an answer but am not seeing any.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your projects jnlp file "template" and add required params directly. The file is named master-application.jnlp and it should be in the root folder of your project.